# What is the highest Format Version of PDF that free software can produce?

Tags: debian, pdf, image-manipulation

I am on Debian Stretch. I made couple of pdf files from `img2pdf` using

```
$ img2pdf --output sample2.pdf sample.jpg
```

I then tried uploading to a web-service and it rejected the pdf file. Looking at the file closely, I realized that it's at ancient 1.3 version -

```
[$] mediainfo sample2.pdf                                                                                            
General
Complete name                            : sample2.pdf
Format                                   : PDF
Format version                           : 1.3
File size                                : 221 KiB

Text
Format                                   : PDF
```

Anybody has any idea why is it ?

Comment: @Fox have you been able to create pdfs with version 1.4 and version 1.5. I am talking about pdf creation, not just viewing pdf versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The various versions of PDF mark the addition of features available in PDF files; this [short history](https://www.prepressure.com/pdf/basics/history) provides a brief summary of the features available in each successive version.

Tools producing PDF files should ideally specify the oldest version which provides the features they need, for each file they produce. The PDF you’re producing with `img2pdf` only uses features available in PDF 1.3 (if that), so it’s correct in specifying version 1.3 in its metadata.

To answer your stated question, [iText](http://developers.itextpdf.com) knows about PDF 2.0. [PDFTeX](http://www.tug.org/applications/pdftex/) can use features from PDF 1.5, and [LibreOffice](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Export_as_PDF) apparently produces version 1.4 files.