# how do I copy or create a new pdf file without password-protection?

Tags: pdf, pdftk

Sometimes I get password-protected pdf files from people with passwords in the mail. It becomes a pain to remember them. The pdf file are usually version 1.4 documents, this information I am sharing is in relation to my [earlier](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/360860/what-is-the-highest-format-version-of-pdf-that-free-software-can-produce) question. Now my question is, is there a way to extract and make a new pdf file from the pdf file, this time without password-protection. I am guessing pdftk could be useful here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends a bit on what kind of pw is set on the pdf. There are user, owner and input passwords.

For userpw:

```
pdftk input.pdf output output.pdf user_pw YOURPASSWORD-HERE
```

with user and ownerpw

```
pdftk input.pdf output output.pdf user_pw YOURPASSWORD-HERE owner_pw YOURPASSWORD-HERE
```

for input pw:

```
pdftk input.pdf output output.pdf input_pw YOURPASSWORD-HERE
```

for more detailed information you can read up here:
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/removing-password-from-pdf-on-linux/

Comment: If you don't want to write your password on the command line, to avoid it being stored, write PROMPT in the place of YOURPASSWORD-HERE. You will be prompted for your password.

Answer (score 1):

`pdftk` can do this if you need a way to do it programatically, but an easy way to get around this is simply open the "secured" file, then choose whatever 'Print to PDF' option you have.

This will create a PDF file that is the same content of the original secured file, but without any metadata (and thus no password).